# Threejs loading models

Tags: three.js

I'm new to three.js, and I'm trying to load in my tree model, but all I see if a blank screen.

I've validated the GLB file using gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com (though the textures didn't seem to load (I'd converted from GLTF to GLB), and I don't get any JS errors in the developer tools, so I'm at a bit of a block (at least mentally).

I've loaded the camera, I've created an Ambient light to light the object (I've reduced the code as it did have directional and point lighting as well).

I'm making the assumption that all objects are loaded at 0,0,0 in terms of coordinates. Does anyone have any experience with GLB files not rendering or where I've gone wrong.

```
import {
    Camera,
    Color,
    Scene,
    PerspectiveCamera,
    WebGLRenderer,
    AmbientLight,
  } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.132.2";
  
  import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.132.2/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

const container = document.querySelector('#scene-container');
const scene = new Scene();
const renderer = new WebGLRenderer();
const hlight = new AmbientLight (0x404040,100);
const fov = 80;
const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
const near = 0.1;
const far = 100; 
const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

scene.background = new Color('white');
camera.position.set(0, 50, 100);
scene.add(hlight);
renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
container.append(renderer.domElement);

loader.load('tree.glb', function(gltf){
  const tree = gltf.scene.children[0];
  tree.scale.set(1.5,1.5,1.5);
  scene.add(gltf.scene);
});
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Comment: It seems you render the scene only once before the model is actually loaded. Try adding a `renderer.render(scene, camera);` in the loader callback function after adding the object to the scene.

Comment: I've add in the wait on the loader and added in the three.js load manager as well, but still no object, I've uploaded the code to a JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/cbruiners/gpfeymtv/4/

Comment: Adding the code to jsfiddle isn't going to help us help you as it wont load your file. What errors do you see in the console?

Comment: There aren't any errors, I added in the Load Manager to write it out to the console and it appears to load fine